# Binary to Decimal conversion VB.net console application

Tags: vb.net, console

I want to convert binary to decimal in vb.net console application. What is the problem in my current code? I can't seem to get correct binary.

```
'Binary Numbers
Dim dec, remainder, m, sum As Integer

m = 1

Console.Write("Enter a decimal Number : ")
dec = Console.ReadLine()
While (dec > 0)

    remainder = dec Mod 2
    sum += m * remainder
    dec = dec / 2
    m = m * 10

End While

c.WriteLine("Binary Numbers = {0} ", sum)
c.ReadKey()
```

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code file to let the compiler tell you about your coding mistakes.  Hopefully you'll discover that Console.WriteLine() already converts from binary to decimal.

Comment: Your question is titled _Binary to Decimal_, your example code converts _Decimal to Binary_, which is it to be?

Answer (score 0):

As Hans said in his comment, you should set `Option Strict On` to disallow automatic conversion that may have unexpected results. You should also validate the user input before trying to convert it to a number.

You can use Convert.ToString to convert decimal numbers directly to binary strings. The following code does that and then (in case you wanted to to code your own loop) is the equivalent of your original loop.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim dec As Integer, decstr As String, binStr As String = ""

        Do
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a decimal number")
            decstr = Console.ReadLine
        Loop Until Integer.TryParse(decstr, dec)
        Console.WriteLine("Using Convert.ToString: {0}", Convert.ToString(dec, 2))

        Do While (dec > 0)
            Dim remainder As Integer = dec Mod 2
            binStr = remainder.ToString & binStr
            dec = dec \ 2
        Loop

        Console.WriteLine("Using loop: {0}", binStr)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```